# How Teams are using ~ and ^ for package.json (angular4) for production builds

Tags: angular, package.json

Our team is using angular4 and Jenkins to do dev and production builds, we are looking for a way to better handle the ~ and ^, for production builds and testing to keep everyone on the same version and not have breaking changes when major releases on an npm (third party) release.  Anyone have any good suggestions or articles to go to to help our team?

Comment: package.lock file!

Comment: looking into this, we do have the generated lock file,  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've been on a few teams facing similar questions.  We struggled with package authors not honoring the semantics of versioning and introducing changes with side effects.  Because of that, we made a team decision not to wild card versions and instead explicitly and deliberately upgrade packages.  In a perfect world, this would not be an issue because the versioning scheme defines pretty clearly what should happen when behaviors or contracts are changed, but we don't live in a perfect world.

Comment: Just made the same decision on my team.
BTW, another potential way to handle this is to either use a newer version of NPM that writes a package.lock file, or yarn, which writes a yarn.lock file, and then version-control the lock file.
Ultimately, though, it's probably easier to just use specific versions in package.json instead of version ranges.